# Could not find member in closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code. `prompt` being a `UIAlertController`.

```
self.presentViewController(prompt, animated: true, completion: {
     prompt.textFields[0].becomeFirstResponder()
})
```

But it gives me this error: `Could not find member 'becomeFirstResponder'`.

Yet, if I put this in it works fine:

```
self.presentViewController(prompt, animated: true, completion: {
     let foo = 0
     prompt.textFields[0].becomeFirstResponder()
})
```

Why does the error go away when I add in a useless line of code such as the above?

Comment: Hmm, yes. I was thinking that. I was going to submit a bug report for this. I'll update the question if I hear anything.

Comment: As an aside, the reason the error appears is because 'becomeFirstResponder' isn't known by AnyObject. Still doesn't answer why the foo line fixes that.

Comment: @Lucas Where does AnyObject come into it? `prompt` is declared just above this piece of code (`var prompt = UIAlertController...`)

Comment: @Newbzors It comes in with the textFields array. Since textFields is just an NSArray, it means it can hold any object. So by accessing the the 0th index of that array, it cannot infer that it is a UITextField. Again, this doesn't answer why the line of 'let foo = 0' fixes it, I'm just stating why I think that line would throw the "Could not find member 'becomeFirstResponder'" error.

Comment: @Lucas Ah, I see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Swift Programming Language book section on If Statements and Forced Unwrapping,

> “You can use an if statement to find out whether an optional contains a value. If an optional does have a value, it evaluates to true; if it has no value at all, it evaluates to false.
>   Once you’re sure that the optional does contain a value, you can access its underlying value”

UIAlertController doesn't have to have textFields, so because the `textFields` array is optional, you have to unwrap it before you can call functions on the objects inside of the array, so it should look something like this:

```
self.presentViewController(prompt, animated: true, completion: {
    if let textFields = prompt.textFields {
       textFields[0].becomeFirstResponder()
    }
})
```

Comment: or `if let textField = textFields[0]` ... that way if the [0] element existed you would enter the code block

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense to me now. I reported a bug to Apple anyway, putting `let foo = 0` should not make the error go away